# Gysin exact sequence for a singular subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, singularity-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (I'm interested in a characteristic $p>0$ specific example) and let $X$ be a (smooth if needed) algebraic variety.

Let $Y \subset X$ be a (possibly) singular closed subvariety of codimension $c$.

I am interested in hypothesis on the singularities of $Y$ that could allow to have a Thom-Gysin isomorphism in étale cohomology 
$$H^{*-2c}_{\text{ét}}(Y; \mathbf Q_\ell(-c)) \simeq H^*_{\text{ét}}(X,X-Y; \mathbf Q_\ell) $$

As mentionned in the answer to the question
[The Gysin long exact sequence for the complement of the zero section of a line bundle over a (possibly) singular base](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89898/the-gysin-long-exact-sequence-for-the-complement-of-the-zero-section-of-a-line-b),
 if $Y$ is the zero section in the total space of a line bundle (and more generally of a vector bundle) over a singular base, there is such an isomorphism.

Moreover, in general, when $Y$ is a complete intersection, there is a well defined morphism:

$$H^{*-2c}_{\text{ét}}(Y; \mathbf Q_\ell(-c)) \to H^*_{\text{ét}}(X,X-Y; \mathbf Q_\ell).$$
(I got this from the article of Joël Riou in the book
"Travaux de Gabber sur l'uniformisation locale et la cohomologie etale des schemas quasi-excellents", Exposé XVI, section 2. It is available at http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3648)

In such generality, it is certainly not an isomorphism, but are there
known conditions on $Y$ that would ensure the previous map to be an isomorphism?